# Keycloak server embedded in a Spring Boot application with custom User Storage SPI

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, keycloak

I have managed to set up a Keycloak server embedded in a Spring Boot Application successfully, following this tutorial:
[Keycloak Embedded in a Spring Boot Application](https://www.baeldung.com/keycloak-embedded-in-spring-boot-app)
in order to avoid setting it up manually.

Since I am dealing with an old implementation that already has it's own DB, I decided to use Keycloak's **User Storage SPI** to connect to an external postgresql DB and use this for authentication instead of Keycloak DB.

To do this, I followed the tutorial on Keycloak documentation, but it envolves a **standalone** Keycloak server, creating a .jar with the custom provider and injecting it to `<pathToKeycloak>/standalone/deployments/`.

I have created an implementation that works with a standalone Keycloak server, but now I want to include it to the embedded one. Is it possible to use a Keycloak server Embedded in a Spring Boot Application and also have an embedded custom User Storage Provider, to avoid setting up manually?

Answer (score 0):

If you have already implemented the provider and the provider factory, you only need to declare the provider factory class in the `resources/META-INF/services/org.keycloak.storage.UserStorageProviderFactory` file.

Then you can log in to the administration console and enable user storage provider on the User Federation page.